# Extract non-repeated values with the same key in array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got this API response of some products in a Vue app:

```
products = [{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "producto02",
    "image": "https://example.com/images/example.png",
    "combinactions": [{
        "id": 1,
        "price": "10.00",
        "price_antes": "10.00",
        "stock": 0,
        "color": "blanco",
        "sex": "masculino",
        "size": "42"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "price": "10.00",
        "price_antes": "10.00",
        "stock": 0,
        "color": "blanco",
        "sex": "masculino",
        "size": "39"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "price": "10.00",
        "price_antes": "10.00",
        "stock": 0,
        "color": "blanco",
        "sex": "masculino",
        "size": "39"
    }, ]
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "producto",
    "image": "https://api.pre.runrunsports.com/api/imagees_productos/figura1_8.png",
    "combinactions": [{
        "id": 33,
        "price": "10.00",
        "price_antes": "10.00",
        "stock": 0,
        "size": "41",
        "sex": "masculino",
        "color": "blanco"
    }, {
        "id": 34,
        "price": "10.00",
        "price_antes": "10.00",
        "stock": 0,
        "size": "41",
        "sex": "masculino",
        "color": "azul"
    }, {
        "id": 35,
        "price": "10.00",
        "price_antes": "10.00",
        "stock": 0,
        "size": "41",
        "sex": "masculino",
        "color": "negro"
    }, {
        "id": 36,
        "price": "10.00",
        "price_antes": "10.00",
        "stock": 0,
        "size": "41",
        "sex": "masculino",
        "color": "rojo"
    }]
}]
```

I'm having a problem with selecting non-repeated values with the same key.
I mean, I want to extract for each product and each attribute product the different values of size, color and sex due to put them in a `<select>`. Then, I will need to **get the matched "price" dynamically depending on the user selection** by sex, color and size.

I'm stuck at this point right now (reduced code):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#list-example',
  data: {
    products: [{
      id: 4,
      name: "producto02",
      image: "https://example.com/images/example.png",
      atributes: {
        "color": "Color",
        "sex": "Sex",
        "size": "Size"
      },
      combinations: [{
          id: 1,
          price: "10.00",
          price_antes: "10.00",
          stock: 0,
          color: "blanco",
          sex: "masculino",
          size: "42"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          price: "10.00",
          price_antes: "10.00",
          stock: 0,
          color: "blanco",
          sex: "masculino",
          size: "39"
        }, {
          id: 3,
          price: "10.00",
          price_antes: "10.00",
          stock: 0,
          color: "blanco",
          sex: "masculino",
          size: "39"
        }
      ]
    }, {
      id: 5,
      name: "producto",
      image: "https://example.com/images/example.png",
      atributes: {
        "color": "Color",
        "sex": "Sex",
        "size": "Size"
      },
      combinations: [{
        id: 33,
        price: "10.00",
        price_antes: "10.00",
        stock: 0,
        size: "41",
        sex: "masculino",
        color: "blanco"
      }, {
        id: 34,
        price: "10.00",
        price_antes: "10.00",
        stock: 0,
        size: "41",
        sex: "masculino",
        color: "azul"
      }, {
        id: 35,
        price: "10.00",
        price_antes: "10.00",
        stock: 0,
        size: "41",
        sex: "masculino",
        color: "negro"
      }]
    }],
  },
  methods: {

  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

span.title {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.price {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
}

select {
  max-width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="list-example">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(product, index) in products" v-bind:key="product.id">
      <span class="title">{{product.name}}</span>
      <div class="form-group valid col-12 field-select" v-for="(atribute, index) in product.atributes" :key="`atribute-${index}`">
        <label v-bind:for="index + product.id"><span>Select {{ atribute }}</span>
                    </label>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <select v-bind:id="index + product.id" class="form-control">
            <option v-for="combination in product.combinations" :key="combination.id">
              {{ combination }}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <span class="price">
      50€ 
    </span>
      <p>(get the price dynamically depending on user selection)</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Many thanks for your time!

Comment: Not really clear to me what you want. You want one select box, or three select boxes?

Comment: @TKoL I want one select per each atribute product. The idea is to display them dynamically depending on the data response API. In this case there are three attributes to get the price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could use Lodash's `uniqBy` method to easily get a list of unique values for each attribute:

```
    <select v-for="(val, attribute) in product.attributes" class="form-control">
        <option v-for="combination in uniqueValsForAttr(product.combinations, attribute)">
            {{ combination }}
        </option>
    </select>

    ...

    methods: {
        uniqueValsForAttr(combinations, attr) {
            return _.uniqBy(combinations, attr).map(item => item[attr]);
        }
    }
```

Then, when you have your selected values, you can find the price with something like this:

```
    getPrice(product, selections) {
        const { color, sex, size } = selections;
        const combination = product.combinations.find(comb => {
            return comb.color === color && comb.sex === sex && comb.size === size;
        });
        return combination.price;
    }
```